# How do I allow pop-ups from local files (file:/// addresses) in Firefox 5?

Tags: javascript, firefox, popup

I've created an HTML file on my local machine that I open using a `file:///` address.  It includes JavaScript that opens new browser windows using `window.open()`.

When I view this page in Firefox 5, the pop-up blocker blocks the new window.  I can't override this behavior; clicking the pop-up blocker "Preferences" shows a menu item "Allow pop-ups for", which has no effect.

How do I allow pop-ups for `file:///` addresses in Firefox 5?

Comment: This might be useful http://old.nabble.com/Firefox-and-popup-whitelist-td22430634.html

Comment: I assume you tried something like `file://*` already?

Comment: I don't think you can. It's a security measure to prevent hostile sites from accessing local files.

Comment: @Joseph: that doesn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do this.

Answer (score 14):

Add <file> to the allowed list under
Preferences/Options -> Content -> Block pop-up windows... Exceptions.

edit: This no longer works, see comments

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in newer Firefox versions. I tried it in Firefox 46 without success.

Comment: Yes looks like they have [disabled it](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=2972093) since 42. Now only works on individual file basis afaict.